# How to re mounted component with composition api in vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html5-video

I want to do a dynamically video player with Artplayer when if changing a route or router pushed or something then application render a new video player with new changed link so I face a problem that's my old videoplayer component can't rewrite instance
i use watchEffect methods to detect route change and try to updated component but it's doesn't work

```
<template>
  <div class="w-full h-full xl:w-9/12">
    <div class="w-full h-96 xl:h-2/3 flex p-6 items-center justify-center">
      <div
        ref="player"
        class="mx-auto w-full h-full"
        v-if="reloadLink.name == this.$route.params.link"
      ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script setup>
import {
  ref,
  reactive,
  onMounted,
  nextTick,
  defineExpose,
  watchEffect,
  onUpdated,
  unmounted,
} from "vue";
import Artplayer from "artplayer";
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";

const route = useRoute();

const options = reactive({
  url: "https://player.vimeo.com/progressive_redirect/playback/364504351/rendition/1080p?loc=external&signature=66193741eea8c35bb1e8ac0c19f96e6d9f825cb04b965e073c3b7573c421eb39",
  title: "One More Time One More Chance",
  poster: "ss",
  volume: 0.5,
  isLive: false,
  muted: false,
  autoplay: false,
  pip: true,
  autoSize: true,
  autoMini: true,
  // screenshot: true,
  setting: true,
  loop: true,
  // flip: true,
  playbackRate: true,
  aspectRatio: true,
  fullscreen: true,
  fullscreenWeb: true,
  // subtitleOffset: true,
  miniProgressBar: true,
  mutex: true,
  backdrop: true,
  theme: "#23ade5",
  lang: navigator.language.toLowerCase(),
  moreVideoAttr: {
    crossOrigin: "anonymous",
  },
  quality: [
    {
      html: "SD 480P",
      url: "https://player.vimeo.com/progressive_redirect/playback/364504351/rendition/1080p?loc=external&signature=66193741eea8c35bb1e8ac0c19f96e6d9f825cb04b965e073c3b7573c421eb39",
    },
    {
      default: true,
      html: "HD 720P",
      url: "https://player.vimeo.com/progressive_redirect/playback/364504351/rendition/1080p?loc=external&signature=66193741eea8c35bb1e8ac0c19f96e6d9f825cb04b965e073c3b7573c421eb39",
    },
  ],
});
const reloadLink = {
  name: "thee",
};
console.log(reloadLink);
// options.url = "https://player.vimeo.com/progressive_redirect/playback/364499803/rendition/1080p?loc=external&oauth2_token_id=1597805160&signature=8bbd350f0737458fbbeba983b73a4d403496eb3ca0df35cda7677ea5239cf7be";
const player = ref(null);
console.log(options.url);

onMounted(() => {
  nextTick(() => {
    new Artplayer({
      ...options,
      container: player.value,
    });
  });
});
watchEffect(() => {
  // reloadLink.value = route.params.link;
  options.url = route.params.link;
  // console.log(options.url);

  reloadLink.name = route.params.link;
  () => {
    options.url = route.params.link;
  };
});
onUpdated(() => {
  options.url = route.params.link;
  unmounted(() => {
     Artplayer;
   });
});

defineExpose({
  player,
  options,
});
</script>
```

Comment: The problem I see is that you don't save Artplayer instance and never destroy it. This is a necessary step for using a lot of third-party libs, and they support that.

Comment: I don't use Vue.js so I'm confused by talk of **routers** etc. Basically are you trying to change a video URL to a different MP4 video using one and same player?

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks for your comment and how i can save instance,

Comment: @VC.One yes. i tried on tag <video src=""> before and it's work, but i'm trying to find more solution for customising video player.

Comment: By assigning the object that `new Artplayer` returns to any variable that you can access, instead of throwing it away. This rule is applicable to any JS API.

Comment: @Thee **(1)** You save the instance into a variable like `var myPlayer = new Artplayer({ ...options, container: player.value, });` not just  using `new Artplayer` which means it goes into nothing (no var) to reference later. **(2)** To change the vid, you can try `myPlayer.url = 'somefile.mp4`. You might get a CORS error in **console** if the URL is outside your site. If you get loading problems then try keeping the 2 test video files on your site (same location as the HTML file). CORS means your site cannot access file in another server (for this problem the solution is to use PHP).

Comment: @Thee Try saving these two files: [test1.mp4](https://filesamples.com/samples/video/mp4/sample_640x360.mp4) and also [test2.mp4](http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4). Put them in your HTML file's folder (or even the `assets` folder if you got such thing). Test the logic of my above comment using these files in your project folder. If successful then try to load online URL (like from Vimeo server). **PS:** Declare `var myPlayer;` first at top (maybe after `const route = ...etc...`) as a **global** var that is seen by all functions then later you update as `myPlayer = ...etc...`

Comment: Thank you for your guys, I spent a times about 30 hours to solve this problem and I did it. lol. it's work when named variable